# Is it necessary to put the object at the principal axis to use $1/f = 1/v - 1/u$?

Tags: optics, lenses

All the derivations I have seen for this equation assume that the object is a point source located along the principal axis. Of course in practice this is rarely the case and we need this formula to be applicable to some object with some height $h$ above the axis. How do we know that $\frac{1}{v} - \frac{1}{u} = \frac{1}{f}$ will still hold if we only considered the very specific case where $h = 0$ in the derivation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Under Gaussian conditions (centered system, rays slightly inclined and not far from the axis) it is very generally demonstrated that the image of a front plane is a front plane. And so for the same $u$ we have the same $v$, independently of $h$.

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: What do you mean by a front plane? And how is it demonstrated?

Thanks for the response :)

Comment: A plane perpendicular to the axis of symmetry of the centered optical system. Maybe I'm not using the correct expression in English (front plan in French)

I will see if I find an elementary proof and I will complete in this case.

Comment: I've got it thanks :). Tried redoing the proof with some height h for the object and h' for the image, where h' = -vh/u (we know it has to be this such that it will intersect with the undeviated ray which goes through the centre of the lens). Churned through the algebra and the h's cancel so we end up with the quantity 1/v - 1/u not depending on h, which of course is what we want because it means that if the proof is valid for the point source case, it will be valid for all heights above the principal axis such that h<<u for paraxial approximation to still be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't necessary. But aberrations may be smaller there. In particular, the focal length can change a little as you move off axis. This is called spherical aberration. For this reason, focal length is defined using the rays very close to the axis.

$1/f = 1/u - 1/v$ may be accurate enough over the whole field of view. Or it may not. It depends on what you are trying to do. For example, if you are designing a camera lens, you would only use the formula to roughly lay out the lens elements. You would then switch to ray tracing to get an accurate picture over the field of view, at large and small apertures, and at different wavelengths.

But if you just want to set up a simple magnifying glass, an approximation is probably good enough.

See this [HyperPhysics page](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/lenscon.html#c1) for an introduction. Or this [RP Photonics Encyclopedia article](https://www.rp-photonics.com/optical_aberrations.html) for a start on deeper information.